# Boolean AND Gate

Tags: circuitikz

I cannot figure out how I can to draw and label a single AND gate. All of the online examples are horizontally aligned. I drew the image. Please anyone show me how do this in LaTeX.

Edited to clarify: Also, I want to label the wires in 3 places each as I show in the image.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the labels like you want them are possible with `circuitikz`. The label options are very limited. Perhaps it is possible to draw everything as a normal `tikz` and get the labels correct.

Answer (score 9):

Following Mythio's suggestion, you can use "pure" TikZ code to locate the labels.

Here is how it works:

- draw the AND port and remember to give it a name because in such a way later on you can access the inputs and output pins; for example:

  ```
  \draw (0,0) node[rotate=90,and port] () {};
  ```

[image]

- the blue circle represents the exact coordinates of the inputs and output pin: this means that to locate the labels `a,b,c` you need to shift a bit that positions:

  ```
  % labels a, b, c
  \node[right=0.01cm,yshift=4pt] at (andp.in 1) {a};
  \node[right=0.01cm,yshift=4pt] at (andp.in 2) {b};
  \node[right=0.01cm,yshift=-4pt] at (andp.out) {c};
  ```
- always starting from that coordinates, the last step is to extend the wires in order to have space to locate the last labels representing the bits entering/exiting the port:

  ```
  % other labels
  \draw (andp.in 1) --++(0,-0.5) node[pos=0.65]{y0 y1};
  \draw (andp.in 2) --++(0,-0.5) node[right,pos=0.65]{z0 z1};
  \draw (andp.out) --++(0,0.5) node[right,pos=0.65]{x0 x1};
  ```

With the syntax `--++(<x,y>)` we are saying that the wire ends in a position that is the sum of the initial one plus `<x,y>` specified.

The whole code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,png,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}    

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[inner sep=0pt,font=\tiny,text height=3pt,text width=15pt]
\draw (0,0) node[rotate=90,and port] (andp) {};

% labels a, b, c
\node[right=0.01cm,yshift=4pt] at (andp.in 1) {a};
\node[right=0.01cm,yshift=4pt] at (andp.in 2) {b};
\node[right=0.01cm,yshift=-4pt] at (andp.out) {c};

% other labels
\draw (andp.in 1) --++(0,-0.5) node[pos=0.65]{y0 y1};
\draw (andp.in 2) --++(0,-0.5) node[right,pos=0.65]{z0 z1};
\draw (andp.out) --++(0,0.5) node[right,pos=0.65]{x0 x1};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Some other options have been set in the code:

1. `inner sep=0pt` to let nodes do not occupy too much space (look in the pgfmanual for the exact use of this option);
2. `font=\tiny` sets the font size of the labels;
3. `text height=3pt` in this example allows labels `a,b` be vertical aligned on the same baseline;
4. `text width=15pt` is used in order to have automatically labels `x0,x1 - y0,y1 - z0,z1` on new line (again, see on the pgfmanual how to use this option in general);
5. `pos=0.65` represents the position of the labels within the extended wire.

---

To connect this port with extended wires to other logic ports, using `coordinates` is of help. To mark exactly the end position of the extended wires one could do:

```
\draw (andp.in 1) --++(0,-0.5) coordinate (a) node[pos=0.65]{y0 y1};
\draw (andp.in 2) --++(0,-0.5) coordinate (b) node[right,pos=0.65]{z0 z1};
```

and later on use `(a)` and `(b)` as reference.

An example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,png,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}    

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[inner sep=0pt,font=\tiny,text height=3pt,text width=15pt]
\draw 
 (1,2.5) node[rotate=90,and port] (andp) {}
 (2,0) node[rotate=90,and port] (andp1) {}
 (0,0) node[rotate=90,and port] (andp2) {};

% labels a, b, c
\node[right=0.01cm,yshift=4pt] at (andp.in 1) {a};
\node[right=0.01cm,yshift=4pt] at (andp.in 2) {b};
\node[right=0.01cm,yshift=-4pt] at (andp.out) {c};

% other labels
\draw (andp.in 1) --++(0,-0.5) coordinate (a) node[pos=0.65]{y0 y1};
\draw (andp.in 2) --++(0,-0.5) coordinate (b) node[right,pos=0.65]{z0 z1};
\draw (andp.out) --++(0,0.5) node[right,pos=0.65]{x0 x1};

% connections
\draw (andp1.out)-|(b)
 (andp2.out)-|(a);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I forgot about this question, but this is a really nice solution Claudio.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with rotation. Using the `circuitikz` package you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[rotate=90,and port] (myand1) {}
(2,0) node[rotate=90,and port] (myand2) {}
(1,2) node[rotate=90,xnor port] (myxnor) {}
(myand1.out) -- (myxnor.in 1)
(myand2.out) -- (myxnor.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: But also, how I can label the gate in 3 places per wire as I shown in picture?